# Как обернуть форму в jQuery переменную?

Tags: jquery

Есть форма. В форме поля. Например имя, товар, размер, кнопка отправки.  Нужно на jQuery добавить функционал. А именно, что бы форма стала расширяемой. То есть появилась кнопка и при нажатии на нее добавлялись еще поля товар, размер. Таким образом каждый раз при нажатии на эту кнопку появлялись снова и снова два поля. Увеличивая количество полей в форме. То есть сколько нужно пользователю.

Далее он вписывает имя (один раз) товар, и размер в соответствии с тем сколько полей создал. После отправляет. Проблема в том, что форма изначально создана из трех полей по этому берем первое поле и первый набор товар, размер и отправляем, потом первое поле и второй набор товар, размер и отправляем и т.д.

Решено было обернуть каждое ново созданные поля (товар и размер) в div с спец id что бы потом при отправке вынимать из этого и компоновать с полем имя, а уже потом отправлять.

Создаем кнопку

```
`jQuery(".buttons-block").before('<button type="button" class="addPosition">Добавить позицию</button>');`
```

Затем копируем все div в которых есть поля товар, размер. Эти дивы имеют класс .formsRightAlign

`form = jQuery(".formsRightAlign").parent("div").clone();`

Вот при клике пытаюсь обернуть 
`jQuery(".addPosition").click(function(){jQuery(".addPosition").wrap('<div class="new"></div>');}`

Затем при нажатие на submint буду запускать функцию которая возмет имя и первое значение и отправит. Как обернуть в div или может лучше другим образом реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".addPosition").click(function() {
  var form = $(".formsRightAlign").parent("div").clone();
  $(".addPosition").before(form.wrap('<marker></marker>'));
});
```